# Changing a Magento default theme

Tags: magento, themes

My understanding of Magento is that you can only have 2 themes loaded at any one time. ( according to the [Magento design guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes#head-hierarchy-of-themes))

Also, that there is two types of themes - default and non-default (i.e. default contain all possible options, non-default override a subset).

All the documentation I've read says that both default and non-default themes are set in the configuration-> section. I don't see how I can have a customised default theme (not called default) and non-default theme at the same time. Do I have to rename my theme to default in order to use non-default themes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the wrong idea.... 3 themes are loaded.

According to the hierarchy, from lowest priority to highest-

**default** - this theme must be called default. I will be planning on using the magento default theme untouched as this theme. This cannot be currently overwriten.

**your custom default theme** - specified in configuration->design->theme->default
I will be using the Magento blank theme as base for developing an everyday store theme.

**your custom non-default theme** - specified in configuration->design->theme->(layout, templates and skin)
I will be using this to create special occasion themes, e.g. Christmas or sale, that will override only a subset of the default theme.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with your own magento custom theme development and also put your name instead of using default or else, and also copy all the templates files and layout XML files and save it in your theme folder. same way repeat the things with the Skin folder also.

**Default folder structure** 
Template and XML files >magento>> app >> design >> front-end ?? base or default >> theme-name 
SKIN - CSS and JS files >magento >> skin >> front-end >> base or default >> theme name
now just copy and paste the theme files from above structure and paste it to the same place and just change the name to base or default to you favorite name.

NOw go to admin >> system >> design >> and Add custom magento theme >> here you will see the theme which you have created in folder structure, just select and save the theme and then just delete or refresh the cache and refresh your web page thata all.

Thanks 
Magento Development